# Retrieving creation date of iPhone Reminders

Tags: iphone, icloud

Does the iPhone ≪Reminders≫ app store creation dates of the reminder lists and the individual items thereof?

Is there **any way** to retrieve the information using iCloud, PhoneView, iFunBox, etc?

Answer (score 3):

You can open them on macos (osx) and export (file -> export). Then you'd get a raw version where you'd find `CREATED` field.